# Opera Mobile incorrectly calculates position: fixed

Tags: html, css-position, opera-mobile

I have a interesting problem with position: fixed in Opera Mobile 11:

Test page: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/841468/testcase/opera/fixed.html

The red `<div>` should stay fixed on top. If I scroll page down, element moves a bit from top edge of viewport (exactly 93px in device pixels); but if I scroll up, element returns to correct position.

(Screenshot on HTC Desire):

[image: Screenshot on HTC Desire]

My findings:

- Changing zoom level didn't help and didn't change element position from top edge.
- It works correctly in Opera Mobile emulators (both 10.1b and 11)
- Setting or removing "top" / "left" properties didn't help
- Setting "z-index" or "display" properties to some value didn't fixed it
- It shows this behavior even when I move viewport with `window.scrollTo(x, y)`
- Setting "zoom" to "reset" didn't work
- Mouse events get through this element to element under it (if it is in that incorrect position)
- Trying IE hacks didn't work :)

Thanks

Comment: Info: Also broken in Opera Mobile 11.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue has been fixed internally, and the Opera Mobile 11.5 version should roll out with this working correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no fix for this, it seems to be a known bug at Opera and they are working on it.
I worked around this bug by using a little Opera specific CSS hack and putting the div to position absolute in the mean time:

noindex:-o-prefocus, div { position: absolute; }

Comment: I just verified in Opera 11.5 and can confirm that this is fixed.
It now behaves as in Firefox Mobile, meaning the fixed position stays at the initial position before re-appearing into place…
I suppose this is caused by performance issues but this isn't an elegant solution :(

Answer (score 0):

It is a known issue at Opera and we are actively working on a fix. It is though a complex issue involving the painting when rendering.