# CSS - HTML tag not 100% of page

Tags: html, css

Why is body, html, and #black sizing to the size of the viewport and not the document height?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<style>

html, body{
height:100%;
}


#black{
position:absolute;
width:100%;
min-height:100%;
height:100%;
background-color:#000000;
z-index:1000;
}

#shell{
height:962px;
width:972px;
margin:0 auto;

}
</style>

</head>

<body>
<div id="black"></div>

<div id="shell">


</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 100% width or height?

Comment: This is interesting. You want `#black` and `#shell` to have the same height, am I right?

Comment: For a start HTML and Body should be the document height, not the viewport height, that is the problem. But then #Black should also be the document height. #Shell should be the fixed height stated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set your body and html tags to `height: 100%`. This "locks" them to the viewport height and then `#black` inherits that height. You need to use `min-height`:

```
html, body{
    min-height:100%;
}
```

UPDATE:

Forgot to mention something. Add this as well:

```
body {
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: That seems to fix html and body but #black is still at the viewport height using height1:00% or min-height:100%

Comment: Position fixed has solved this when adding to #black

Comment: Ok. I guess any position other than default fixes it. Don't ask me why though :)

Comment: Although I still have the same problem on Opera mobile - with fixed.

Comment: Did you try what I suggested in my update instead of using `fixed`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
body, html {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
#black {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%:
}
```

Comment: @user1209203 I have saved your html as a file using my css and it works. The black color fills all the page.

Comment: So then scroll down and it ends at the viewport height

Comment: @TrungDQ: Try resizing your browser window to less than 962px height. You get a scoll bar and white space below the black.

Comment: @user1209203 I have updated my answer. Then you can see the black everywhere. That is the only way I can think about if you don't want to move your `#shell` into the `#black`.

Comment: Not on Opera mobile though :(

Comment: @user1209203 according to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/7851316/1420186 you may need to update your browser. But I always wonder why don't you use `body { background-color: black; }`.

Comment: the black is and overlay to fade from black

Answer (score -1):

Because you said so. Saying

```
#black {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

does set [`width`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-width-property) and [`height`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-height-property) to `100%` of the [containing block](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#containing-block)'s size. The containing block in this case is the [viewport](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#containing-block-details).

When you want `#black` to cover the whole content, you must give it a different containing block. This can be done by [`position`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#choose-position)ing `body`

```
body {
    position: relative;
}
```

Now it covers the height. To do the same for the width, you can either set a width on body

```
body {
    position: relative;
    width: 972px;
}
```

or float body

```
body {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
```

See full [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5CkMA/)